# Windows IoT core image helper browse option is disabled

Tags: windows-10, raspberry-pi2, iot, windows-10-iot-core

[image]How to enable IoT core image helper browse option?

I'm using Windows 10 home basic. My board is Raspberry pi 2 and I followed all instruction from here: http://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/SetupRPI.htm

I'm using SanDisk Ultra 16GB class 10 SD card and I'm able to detect SD card. However, browse option to select image is grayed out. How can I enable this?

Answer (score 1):

Just select "I: 14Gb [SD Card]" then you can click browse button.

Answer (score 0):

I have not selected the SD card. To make browse option enable, we need to select that. Hope this helps someone. Thanks.